# What are the different Direction properties I can use on an Angular Material Menu Component?

Tags: angular-material2

From the [Angular Material Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api) I can use a `direction` attribute on a Menu Component:

> `direction: Direction` : Layout direction of the menu.

This means that there is a type, `Direction`, but I am not able to find it, and do not know how to use it on a menu component.

I have tried the following, but I am not sure which values I can put inside the `direction`-attribute. I thought I could use something like `Direction.UP` or `Direction.DOWN`, but I am not able to find the `Direction` class in my project. Is there a hidden place to import it from?

```
<button mat-raised-button type="button" [matMenuTriggerFor]="saveBtn" color="primary">Ny rad</button>
<mat-menu #saveBtn="matMenu" [direction]="'up'"> <!-- Here I am using [direction], but do not know what to put as a value there, that is of type Direction -->
<button mat-menu-item (click)="save('1')">Save 1</button>
<button mat-menu-item (click)="save('2')">Save 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

***EDIT***

After searching for a while longer, I found that I could use the values `'ltr'` and `'rtl'`, and I had to use it on an element that uses the `matMenuTriggerFor`- selector.

After declaring a variable with the type `Direction` in Visual Studio Code, it suggested me to `import { Direction } from '@angular/cdk/bidi';`, and that type looked like this:

```
export declare type Direction = 'ltr' | 'rtl';
```

Even though I found this, I am getting an error stating that

> Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'direction' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-menu'.

when I try to use the `direction` attribute on the `mat-menu`-element, even though the documentation says I can use a direction attribute. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mat-menu` will inherit the `dir` attribute from the parent container without importing the `cdk` ... please note the `dir="rtl"` on the parent div

```
<div dir="rtl">  
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </mat-menu>
</div>
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ol2cz5?embed=1&file=app/menu-overview-example.html

**Revision**

`mat-menu` imports the `cdk/bidi` automagically from the `menu-directive.ts` here.

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/0b19b586d81feb667958152d033fd4c461a7479c/src/lib/menu/menu-directive.ts#L10

Within `directionality.ts` in the bidi, this line defines ltr by default if nothing is specified.

```
this.value = (value === 'ltr' || value === 'rtl') ? value : 'ltr';
```

- Please also note the lines above this line of code when reviewing the hyperlink... as this is how `directionality.ts` is getting this value from the parent container or the global document.
- For this attribute `ltr` and `rtl` are your only options.
- If you are looking for above, below, left or right, please reference the answer about x and y position attributes as the `dir` will not be the one you are looking for.

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/0b19b586d81feb667958152d033fd4c461a7479c/src/cdk/bidi/directionality.ts#L37

Comment: I do not feel the answer is exactly what I am looking for, but it certainly  explains some of the behaviour using the `direction`-attribute. You can also add that `ltr` is an option to use in the dir-attribute.

Comment: please see revision for further detail.

Answer (score 9):

You're probably looking for a way to customize the position of the menu.

If so, you can use the `yPosition` and/or `xPosition` attributes to change where the menu shows.

Here's what the attributes represent:

- `yPosition`

  - The position of the menu in the Y/vertical axis
  - Valid values: `above` | `below`
  - Example:

    ```html
    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
        <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <!-- Shows the menu above the button/trigger -->
    <mat-menu yPosition="above" #appMenu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>Settings</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Log out</button>
    </mat-menu>
    ```
- `xPosition`

  - The position of the menu in the X/horizontal axis
  - Valid values: `before` | `after`
  - Example:

    ```html
    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
        <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <!-- Shows the menu before the button/trigger -->
    <mat-menu xPosition="before" #appMenu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>Settings</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Log out</button>
    </mat-menu>
    ```

For more information, check out the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#customizing-menu-position).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My initial wish was exactly as you propose, meaning I was looking at the wrong attribute to begin with. However, this does not answer the question I was asking, but I'll give you an upvote for the effort :)

Answer (score 3):

The `Direction` type is part of the Bi-directionality API in Angular CDK library. Like any other feature, you need to import its module into your application (e.g. app.module.ts) in order to use it:

```
import {BidiModule} from '@angular/cdk/bidi';
```

More details are in [the API docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/bidi/api).